# Proportion of the sums or average proportion of the parts?

Tags: mean, proportion, sum

Here’s a curiosity that come up during a work discussion.  While this example uses financial data, it has a statistical question at its heart.

Consider the following table with a budget and actual spend for a project (simplified example).  The third column is the proportion of the spend to the budget for each activity. (This is normally expressed as a percentage, but we will keep it as a proportion here).

[image]

As can be seen the proportion, across the project, when taking the sums of the budget and spend is 1.03.

$$\rho_1=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i} {\sum\limits_{i=1}^n b_i }=\frac{85,511} {83,000} = 1.03$$

However, if we take the individual activities the average proportion across the project is 1.11.

$$\rho_2=\frac{{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)_i}} {n}=\frac{11.1} {10} = 1.11$$

I am aware that, in general, ${\rho_1 \neq \rho_2}$. However, from a statistical point of view, which is the ‘true’ measure of the expected proportion between the budget and actual spend?

This is not a trivial example as the second approach has a variance that is greater than 10% variance which, for this project, has some wider contractual implications.  If the first approach is taken, then those implications are relaxed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which is the ‘true’ measure of the expected proportion between the
> budget and actual spend?

The second one: $\rho_2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{a_i}{b_i}\right) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)_i = 111,15\%$

The other statistic is the proportion of budget of all the projects listed $\rho_1 = 103,03\%$.

Suppose you add another activity with Budget $10.000\$$ and Actual Spend $10.000\$$. We're adding a proportion of budget of $1.00$. The proportion of budget for the whole sample is now $\rho_1 = 102,70\%$ and the mean of the proportions becomes $110,14\%$.

Now suppose instead that the additional activity has Budget $50.000\$$ and Actual Spend $50.000\$$. The new proportion of the budget of the whole sample becomes $101,89\%$ but the mean of the proportions remains $\rho_2 = 110,14\%$.